# how can i create S3 Lifecycle configuration using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I tried to use newer_noncurrent_versions in S3 Lifecycle.

In [Terraform 4.3.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v4.3.0), lifecycle was released.

However, when applying on Terraform cloud, an error saying to use Lifecycle V2 occurred.

Is my code the problem? Is it a terraform provider problem?

#### Terraform CLI and Terraform AWS Provider Version

```
Terraform v1.1.5
on darwin_amd64
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3" {
  bucket = "aws-test-bucket"

  rule {
    id     = "rule"
    status = "Enabled"

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days                  = 1
      newer_noncurrent_versions = 2
    }
  }
}
```

#### Actual Behavior

- When I run `terrafrom plan` on local, it seems to be created just fine.

```
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3" {
      + bucket = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + rule {
          + id     = "rule"
          + status = "Enabled"

          + noncurrent_version_expiration {
              + newer_noncurrent_versions = 2
              + noncurrent_days                  = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

**However, when applying in Terraform Cloud, the following error occurs.**

```
Error: error creating S3 Lifecycle Configuration for bucket (aws-test-bucket): InvalidRequest: 
NewerNoncurrentVersions element can only be used in Lifecycle V2. 
status code: 400, with aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.s3
on s3.tf line 66, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3":
```

Comment: @Marcin Nope! Very clearly thanks to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are missing `filter` in the rule:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "s3" {
  bucket = "aws-test-bucket"

  rule {
    id     = "rule"
    status = "Enabled"
    
    filter {} 

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days                  = 1
      newer_noncurrent_versions = 2
    }
  }
  
}
```